# How to use children in vue?

Tags: vue.js, wrapper

I am using `React.js` and `Vue.js` for frontend in my different projects.

In React, I am able to wrap templates with `MyComponent` like this.

```
    <MyComponent>
      <div>Here</div>
    </MyComponent>
```

And in MyComponent file

```
const MyComponent = ({children}) {
    return (
         <div className="my-component">{children}</div>
    )
}
```

How can I use this simple technique in `Vue.js`???

Comment: You'll want to use Slots. Read more from here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use [Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Slot-Content).

Here is an example taken from vuejs doc

Component template:

```
<a :href="url">
  <slot></slot>
</a>
```

The code:

```
<navigation-link url="/profile">
  Your Profile
</navigation-link>
```

`<slot></slot>` will be replaced by what's inside the component tags. It will be rendered as:

```
<a url="/profile">
  Your Profile
</a>
```